# Delphi ReadProcessMemory From Notepad

Tags: string, delphi, notepad, readprocessmemory

I want to extract the full process memory of notepad process and write it to a text file.
The problem is that i do not find what i type in notepad in the textfile.
For example, if i type "test123" in notepad, i cannot find the string in the textfile that the program creates.
Here is the code:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows,
  TLHelp32,
  SysUtils;

var
  Snap, err: dword;
  sysinfo: TSystemInfo;
  Process: TPROCESSENTRY32;
  Handle: THandle;
  Mbi: TMemoryBasicInformation;
  Addr, BytesRead: dword;
  Buf: PChar;
  f: TextFile;
begin
  GetSystemInfo(sysinfo);
        Handle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, 2928);
        if Handle <> 0 then
        begin
          writeln(Process.szExeFile);
          Addr := dword(sysinfo.lpMinimumApplicationAddress);
          while (Addr < $80000000) do
          begin
            if VirtualQueryEx(Handle, Ptr(Addr), Mbi, SizeOf(Mbi)) = 0 then
            begin
              err := GetLastError;
              inc(Addr, sysinfo.dwPageSize);
              continue;
            end;
             Buf := AllocMem(Mbi.RegionSize);
             ReadProcessMemory(Handle, Mbi.BaseAddress, Buf, Mbi.RegionSize, BytesRead);
             AssignFile(f, 'Test.txt');
             Append(f);
             WriteLn(f, Buf);
             CloseFile(f);
             FreeMem(Buf);
            if Addr + Mbi.RegionSize < Addr then
              break;
            Addr := Addr + Mbi.RegionSize;
          end;
          CloseHandle(Handle)
        end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: You wouldn't be able to use a text file to write the memory content like that in the first place; it's not text. What are you actually trying to accomplish? (Why do you want to read the process memory to get the text?)

Comment: i want to extract some email addresses from a process memory. How can i do that? Is there a way to convert the output to text?

Comment: You are writing malware huh?

Comment: I have a email extractor and i do not have the serial key to export e-mails.

Comment: Do not struggle, you can dump your target process to file and analyse its memory layout.

Comment: If you cannot help me, please do not comment anymore. Bye!

Comment: You will not get any help here on Stack Overflow with an attitude like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **correct** way to retrieve notepad's text content is to locate the `HWND` of notepad's edit field, using `FindWindowEx()` or `EnumChildWindows()` or similar, and then send it a `WM_GETTEXT` message.

But if you must dump Notepad's allocated memory, then you need to fix your code.  It is ignoring errors, and not writing the retrieved data to your file correctly.  Try something more like this instead:

```
uses
  Windows,
  TLHelp32,
  SysUtils;

var
  err: DWORD;
  sysinfo: TSystemInfo;
  Handle: THandle;
  Mbi: TMemoryBasicInformation;
  Addr: DWORD_PTR;
  BytesRead: DWORD;
  Buf: array of Byte;
  f: TFileStream;
begin
  GetSystemInfo(sysinfo);
  Handle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, 2928);
  if Handle = 0 then
  begin
    err := GetLastError;
    // do something...
  end else
  try
    f := TFileStream.Create('Test.txt', fmCreate);
    try
      Addr := DWORD_PTR(SysInfo.lpMinimumApplicationAddress);
      while (Addr < $80000000) do
      begin
        if VirtualQueryEx(Handle, Pointer(Addr), Mbi, SizeOf(Mbi)) = 0 then
        begin
          err := GetLastError;
          Inc(Addr, sysinfo.dwPageSize);
          Continue;
        end;
        if Mbi.RegionSize > Length(Buf) then
          SetLength(Buf, Mbi.RegionSize);
        if not ReadProcessMemory(Handle, Mbi.BaseAddress, @Buf[0], Mbi.RegionSize, BytesRead) then
        begin
            err := GetLastError;
            // do something...
        end else
          f.WriteBuffer(Buf[0], BytesRead);
        if Addr + Mbi.RegionSize < Addr then
          break;
        Addr := Addr + Mbi.RegionSize;
      end;
    finally
      f.Free;
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(Handle);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: The **correct** way is in fact to use the automation API.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad presumably stores its text encoded in the Windows native UTF-16. So look for that text as a wide string.

I guess the other problem is that you are writing binary data to a text file. Any null characters in your memory blocks will terminate the output. You really want to stop using Pascal I/O and just dump this memory to a file stream. Or if you have to use Pascal I/O at least to it in binary mode.

Wouldn't it just be easier to use the automation API or send WM_GETTEXT?

Comment: Should i use WM_GETTEXT after i read the memory?

Comment: No. For notepad you can read with WM_GETTEXT alone.

Comment: Notepad is just for testing. Can i use WM_GETTEXT for readprocessmemory output?

Comment: Of course not. You send that to a window. Your question declares that your interest is in notepad.

Comment: is there a way to convert the readprocessmemory output to text?

Comment: Maybe. Do you know the layout? Do you know what UTF-16 is?

Comment: Is that no to both questions? Anyway, if you don't know the layout you'll have to hunt for the text. If you don't know what UTF-16 is you need to do some learning before proceeding.